# No se ha cargado ninguna de las imágenes ni el estilo css de mi página web de Django

Tags: css, django, imagen, heroku, static

He lanzado la web de [este repositorio de githu](https://github.com/antoinecomp/dos_website)b en [esta url](https://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/) con Heroku pero como podéis ver no hay imágenes ni estilo .css. Como es posible y como resolver este problema?

```
2021-07-17T21:11:31.115305+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-07-17T21:11:32.189726+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.32.150.15 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8379 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win
64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:32.191300+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=4ac7c234-855b-4ac4-aaee-56746352ec73
fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=93ms status=200 bytes=8620 protocol=https
2021-07-17T21:11:32.206068+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.232.224 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8379 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Wi
n64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:32.206552+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=72da5619-c34f-4d19-a069-339cc3d38088
fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=61ms status=200 bytes=8620 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:32.653544+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.32.150.15 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8379 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win
64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:32.654864+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=dcf31e75-36a3-4b1e-b7b3-fa9631278f69
fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=8620 protocol=https
2021-07-17T21:11:32.656678+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.232.224 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:32 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 4
04 179 "http://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537
.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:32.657225+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com req
uest_id=d27178a7-957f-43d6-b882-0aadcbb3a77a fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:32.793263+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.232.224 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:32 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/
1.1" 404 179 "http://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safa
ri/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:32.793643+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.c
om request_id=351351d4-e377-4ff3-8ba6-9d46b5b26dff fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:32.821653+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.39.160.97 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:32 +0000] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "http://dosmusical.
herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:32.823575+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/style.css" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=516b455e-b694-4a1
c-9aa7-357f0669dd42 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:32.923910+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.14.66.122 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:32 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "http
://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:32.924719+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=250
59456-fa6f-4fc5-8c26-da18c699c69f fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:32.934209+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.232.224 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:32 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/popper/popper.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "htt
p://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:32.938273+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/popper/popper.min.js" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=c73
794a5-c5ed-4c1d-ba56-318a873fc3e7 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:32.971590+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.39.160.97 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:32 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404
179 "http://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36
"
2021-07-17T21:11:32.973888+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com reque
st_id=46fffa47-97ce-42d5-adf7-00635cb08e80 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-07-17T21:11:33.075027+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/img/initial.jpg" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=46437e1d-7de1-4
969-baf0-e56415229798 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:33.075225+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.14.66.122 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:33 +0000] "GET /static/img/initial.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "http://dosmusica
l.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:33.076396+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.232.224 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:33 +0000] "GET /static/img/aimerestplusfortquedetreaime.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404
 179 "http://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.3
6"
2021-07-17T21:11:33.076776+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/img/aimerestplusfortquedetreaime.jpg" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com reque
st_id=b3752fde-8537-49ce-8261-8ad35d42a5b5 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:33.137536+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.39.160.97 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:33 +0000] "GET /static/img/anais.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "http://dosmusical.
herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:33.139258+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/img/anais.jpg" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=0d5bde87-9030-426
6-8d31-b6faa0fa171c fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:33.320205+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.39.160.97 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:33 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "http://dosmusical.herokuapp
.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:33.321938+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=5c38d86e-37bf-4887-b691-0a
98c6d1f9ce fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:36.976771+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.39.160.97 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8379 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win
64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:36.978536+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=90333a66-7dd4-4773-a1ad-7fe3bd1db539
fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=8620 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:37.172159+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.232.224 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:37 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/
1.1" 404 179 "http://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safa
ri/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:37.172746+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.c
om request_id=2f9586c2-3d38-490d-8f98-6508db575345 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:37.190332+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.14.66.122 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:37 +0000] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "http://dosmusical.
herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:37.190413+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/style.css" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=9c98f379-a1b3-445
d-806f-cca25c7901c3 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:37.192904+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.39.160.97 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:37 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 40
4 179 "http://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.
36"
2021-07-17T21:11:37.194527+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com req
uest_id=a543c8b3-122b-4444-9925-a214b52942c5 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:37.213807+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.10.67.12 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:37 +0000] "GET /static/img/aimerestplusfortquedetreaime.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1
79 "http://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:37.214750+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/img/aimerestplusfortquedetreaime.jpg" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com reque
st_id=a9495771-0d6a-4d9c-a135-fe024db1563f fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:37.215538+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.124.73 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:37 +0000] "GET /static/img/anais.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "http://dosmusical.
herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:37.215987+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/img/anais.jpg" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=7a1928a7-23e2-470
0-a643-6fba5a4cc2b9 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:37.432897+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.232.224 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:37 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "htt
p://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:37.433851+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=d13
855f8-4776-48b4-8a0e-461e6dfa2b9d fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:37.455226+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.39.160.97 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:37 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404
179 "http://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36
"
2021-07-17T21:11:37.457193+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com reque
st_id=6194c67b-8b35-45f0-96ea-5fc2a9dccf72 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:37.459900+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.14.66.122 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:37 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/popper/popper.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "http
://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:37.460022+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/popper/popper.min.js" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=209
9cb42-fd88-4660-b574-dea6e5d9b958 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:37.612083+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.14.66.122 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:37 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404
179 "http://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36
"
2021-07-17T21:11:37.612085+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com reque
st_id=93685d50-00e6-44b1-a0b6-1cddcce109f5 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:37.707679+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.169.102 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:37 +0000] "GET /static/img/initial.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "http://dosmusic
al.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:37.709034+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/img/initial.jpg" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=2294c90a-0c51-4
001-9f73-2abab95e8bf0 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:48.800175+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.169.102 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8379 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Wi
n64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:48.801398+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=6fdc6d59-aa97-486f-a1fc-5e945c62c984
fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=8620 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:48.996400+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.169.102 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:48 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 4
04 179 "http://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537
.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:48.997967+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com req
uest_id=8acf1536-190a-49a0-929c-b31e3ed11e09 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:49.000523+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.14.66.122 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:48 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1
.1" 404 179 "http://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safar
i/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:49.001728+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.c
om request_id=64ffa20e-8e02-46a7-8d48-d216cc377f8d fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:49.002240+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.39.160.97 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:48 +0000] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "http://dosmusical.
herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:49.006082+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/style.css" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=d2ae294a-0876-433
b-bfbf-defaeda70953 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:49.027667+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.124.73 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:49 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/popper/popper.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "http
://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:49.028079+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/popper/popper.min.js" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=fb2
68089-46d9-4648-af81-fad2324969a8 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:49.040244+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.10.67.12 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:49 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1
79 "http://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:49.041055+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com reque
st_id=364975f5-c2ce-49ce-ba59-e7acaca678ae fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:49.053098+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.232.224 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:49 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "htt
p://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:49.053704+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=0ee
7be3c-26e1-4eda-b2ad-62f22185051d fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=8ms service=12ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:49.155391+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.169.102 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:49 +0000] "GET /static/img/initial.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "http://dosmusic
al.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:49.156499+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/img/initial.jpg" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=e0962fff-889e-4
825-a8ce-9ed43d6d8c48 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:49.167632+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.124.73 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:49 +0000] "GET /static/img/aimerestplusfortquedetreaime.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404
179 "http://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36
"
2021-07-17T21:11:49.167891+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/img/aimerestplusfortquedetreaime.jpg" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com reque
st_id=937d8136-e312-4cbb-8b7f-869ea01320c9 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:49.174266+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.10.67.12 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:49 +0000] "GET /static/img/anais.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "http://dosmusical.h
erokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:49.174878+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/img/anais.jpg" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=35608b89-fd88-4db
e-9ac9-23675eca0308 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:49.242890+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.232.224 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:49 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/popper/popper.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "htt
p://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
2021-07-17T21:11:49.243403+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/popper/popper.min.js" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com request_id=715
c0547-8ffc-454d-b5db-0610f6906a52 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
2021-07-17T21:11:49.412387+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.232.224 - - [17/Jul/2021:21:11:49 +0000] "GET /static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404
 179 "http://dosmusical.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.3
6"
2021-07-17T21:11:49.413091+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" host=dosmusical.herokuapp.com reque
st_id=e73e4959-52e0-4ef1-8983-37fc269d4555 fwd="185.104.137.33" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=http
```

Aqui estan los `settings.py`:

```
"""
Django settings for todowoo project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'dos_website'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

LOGIN_URL = '/login'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta usar el lenguaje que tiene Django para los templates, ver el siguiente  [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/)

En vez de usar:

```
<link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Usa:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

Aplica lo mismo para las imágenes.